# Ruby wrapper (gem) for CA Siteminder authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-sign-on, siteminder

I'm trying to figure out how to login into a CA Siteminder server and issue a put and get request.  The SDK is completely in Java or C++, which I do not understand. What Ruby wrappers(gem) are there that can help with Siteminder authentication (from the client standpoint).

If there is no wrapper, can someone please point me to the best info to learn to open an authentication sessions and learn to issue POST and GET requests.

Answer (score 1):

I've had very good luck using [omniauth-saml](https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml) to integrate a rails app w/ Siteminder.

Comment: Thanks, but is this for the server side or client?  I'm trying to make a connection via Ruby on the client side, basically connect with a HTTP request, with something like open-uri or something.

Comment: I used it to implement both SP & IDP initiated SAML federation between my application and Siteminder. Is that not what you are looking for?